# can't set photo Uri which is taken from firebase current user in circleimageview.?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm setting up profile pic Uri using Userprofileupdaterequest in Firebase auth successfully set and fetched in another activity using Firebase currentuser function as below but couldn't load it in circle ImageView....

```
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

    if (user == null) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    } else {
        String name = user.getDisplayName();
        String email = user.getEmail();
        Uri photoUrl = user.getPhotoUrl();

        tv_username.setText(name);

        Picasso.with(Display.this)
                .load(photoUrl)
                .into(iv_profile);

        // Check if user's email is verified
        boolean emailVerified = user.isEmailVerified();
        String verified;
        if (emailVerified) {
            verified = "success";
        } else {
            verified = "not verified";
        }
        // The user's ID, unique to the Firebase project. Do NOT use this value to
        // authenticate with your backend server, if you have one. Use
        // FirebaseUser.getToken() instead.
        String uid = user.getUid();
        tv_display.setText(email);

        tv_email_verification.setText(verified);
```

debugger report,actual uri is in uriString key thats the uri i should fetch how can i do that..

[image: in this image you guys can see the actual data is in uriString key, wanna fetch that how can i]

Comment: Are you using latest version of `Picasso` if not try to update it. If that doesn't help than try to use `Glide` but if you are 100% sure image url is there.

Comment: if that is the case it couldn't happen for any usage but its happening for other usages...in same project

Answer (score 0):

For me it's working with Picasso, but there are times when user image does not exist. For these cases, I used a default image as placeholder and error images:

```
Picasso.with(this)
        .load(photoUri)
        .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_unknown_user) 
        .error(R.mipmap.ic_unknown_user)        
        .into(imgProfileImage);
```

And in my XML file:

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/imgProfileImage"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_usuario"
    app:border_color="#ffffff"
    app:border_width="2dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
     />
```

Comment: problem for me is that not because of picasso or something else .i am fetching the uri from firebase current user to photourl variable in above program.but its not fetching the actual uri thats the problem..hope you understand..